# Regex replace only inside tag (need help writing regex)

Tags: java, regex

I need to write regex that replaces `a` with `b` but only inside `<pre>` tag.

Example

```
a <pre> c a <foo> a d </pre> a
```

Result

```
a <pre> c b <foo> b d </pre> a
```

Please help writing expression for java `String.replace` function. There is a guarantee that `pre` tag is not nested.

Comment: Cue the torrent of "Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML"...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It isn't html actually, it's my simple markup

Comment: @RuiJarimba trying to write something like `<pre>(.*?)a(.*?)</pre>` -> `$1b$2` but it isn't working

Comment: @Poma please clarify, do you need to change only 'a' characters in <pre> or you need to change whole content in <pre>?

Comment: @Poma: If you post `<pre>...</pre>` and it's not HTML, **you should say that**. The point stands, though: If it's *like* HTML, even if not actually HTML, trying to use regular expressions to deal with it will be painful and time-wasting. Now, if it's not like HTML (you can't nest any tags, for instance [not just not nesting `pre` tags]), you might stand a chance.

Comment: @Taky only 'a' characters, updated example

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ok I can replace `</?pre>` with ` char so it doesn't look like html anymore.

Comment: @Poma: If you change `</?pre>` to a single character value, the required regexes will become **much** simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best you can do with String.replace() is something like:

```
String string = ...
for (;;)
{
    String original = string;
    string = string.replaceFirst("(<pre>.*?)a(.*?</pre>)", "$1b$2");
    if (original.equals(string))
        break;
}
```

(**EDIT**: @Bohemian has noted the above regex doesn't work correctly. So it needs to be changed to:
`(<pre>(?:(?!</pre>).)*a((?:(?!<pre>).)*</pre>)` (untested) to avoid matching outside a `<pre>...</pre>` section.  With this change, we don't need the `*?` quantifier and can use the more common "greedy" (`*`) quantifier. This is starting to look a lot like my other answer, which I only really meant as a joke!)

You're better off using a Matcher (following code off the top of my head):

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=<pre>)(.*?)(?=</pre>)");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(string);
StringBuffer replacement = new StringBuffer();

while (matcher.find())
{
     matcher.appendReplacement(replacement, "");
     // Careful using unknown text in appendReplacement as any "$n" will cause problems
     replacement.append(matcher.group(1).replace("a", "b"));
}    
matcher.appendTail(replacement);
String result = replacement.toString();
```

**Edit**: Changed pattern above so that it does not match surrounding `<pre>` and `</pre>`.

Comment: You are replacing "a" inside <tag> too.

Comment: @AchintyaJha it was my mistake in example. Yes "a" inside <tag> should be replaced

Comment: I think your regex will replace `"a"` in `"<pre>x</pre>a<pre>x</pre>"`

Comment: @Bohemian: I've edited my answer to indicate that the regex is wrong and provided another one

Comment: You could greatly simply your code by using look arounds, and you don't need to be non-greedy (OP guarantees no nesting): `(?<=<pre>).*(?=</pre>)"`. Being non-consuming, lookarounds would mean you don't need to replace the consumed tags.

Comment: You're right, but I think it still needs the non-greedy `.*?` otherwise `<pre> a </pre> x <pre> b </pre>` will scan past the first `</pre>` because it can match the second: `pre` ( `a </pre> x <pre> b` ) `</pre>`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex that will do the job (I think: I wouldn't bet too much on it passing all tests [image] )

```
String replacement = original.replaceAll(
    "(?<=<pre>(?:(?!</pre>).){0,50})a(?=(?:(?!<pre>).)*</pre>)", 
    "b");
```

Explanation:

- `(?<=<pre>(?:(?!</pre>).){0,50})` - look-behind for a preceding
  `<pre>` so long as we don't traverse back over `</pre>` to find it. Java requires a finite maximum length look-behind so we use `{0,50}` rather than `*`.
- `a` - The character we want to replace
- `(?=(?:.(?!<pre>))*</pre>)` - Look ahead for `</pre>` so
  long as we don't traverse past `<pre>` to find it.

Answer (score -1):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<pre>(.+?)</pre>");
java.util.regex.Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("a <pre> c a <tag> a d </pre> a");
```

Try this: